# Azure AD - get Group AD Name via Graph Service or claims

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, claims

I'm trying to get the names of Group Azure AD,
Inside token after Azure Login (openId) I receive group IDs in json But I need Groups names.

Json after login:

[Claims](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnaAN.png)

trying to use GraphService
At Azure portal, create a secret key but when I put these key in AuthenticationHeaderValue my code brokes.

[Portal Azure Add Key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbZvY.png)

```
var graphServiceClientGr = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) => {
                requestMessage
                    .Headers
                    .Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }));
```

My var "token" is the same token which i receive after login, and which have claims inside.

At inner exception i receive:

"Access token validation failure. Invalid audience"

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiEjN.png)

What are the correct parameter i should to put in authentication?

AFter these invocation How i receive the name of GROUP? Any suggestions to do that?
I don't need **role applications Names** because i **need group AD Names**

I think to try with the next line, but i don't know if inside these object I receive names of groups.

In these line, i expect to receive name of groups of these user, who correspon to these login token
[Groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmtm4.png)

or with these line:

[grapServiceClient.Me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wyfY.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure AD issues claims security groups names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52555722/azure-ad-issues-claims-security-groups-names)

Comment: Hey @cm44, I put an code example to recover group names from graph api on other question, take a loog [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60177683/2791237)

Answer (score 1):

According to my research, if we configure `Groups` claim for the Azure AD application, it will just return the ObjectID of groups which the user used to login contains in the group claim value and on-premises group attributes. It cannot return group name. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims).
[image]

So if we want to get the groups name, we can use [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) to get it. But the api will return directory object and group object. So we need to do some process.
For example
1. Register Azure AD application

2. Configure API permissions
   [image]
   [image]
3. Update web.config

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ida:AppID" value="YOUR APP ID" />
    <add key="ida:AppSecret" value="YOUR APP PASSWORD" />
    <add key="ida:RedirectUri" value="https://localhost:PORT/" />
    <add key="ida:AppScopes" value="User.Read Directory.ReadWrite.All Directory.AccessAsUser.All />
</appSettings>
```

4. Add the follwoing code to ```Startup.cs

```
private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification notification)
        {
            var idClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(appId)
                .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
                .WithClientSecret(appSecret)
                .Build();

            string message;
            string debug;

            try
            {
                string[] scopes = graphScopes.Split(' ');

                var result = await idClient.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                    scopes, notification.Code).ExecuteAsync();

                message = "Access token retrieved.";
                debug = result.AccessToken;
            }
            catch (MsalException ex)
            {
                message = "AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync threw an exception";
                debug = ex.Message;
            }

            notification.HandleResponse();
            notification.Response.Redirect($"/Home/Error?message={message}&debug={debug}");
        }
```

5. Call the graph api

```
            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                    async (requestMessage) =>
                    {
                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                    }));
            var results = await graphClient.Me.MemberOf.Request().GetAsync();
            var lists = results.ToList();
            Group group;
            foreach (var a in lists) {

                if (a.GetType() == typeof(Group)) {

                    group = a as Group;
                    var groupId=group.Id;
                    var groupName=group.DisplayName;


                }


            }
```

For more details about how to develop the application, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/aspnet).

Comment: Hi Jim, I'm understand your solution and my code is similar to your code but i dont know how i get "accessToken" variable. Note: i'm using netcore 3.0, aspnetboilerplate with angular8 at fronted